# How to add a suffix to the first N columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, suffix

I want to add a suffix to the first N columns. But I can't.

This is how to add a suffix to all columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {"name" : ["John","Alex","Kate","Martin"], "surname" : ["Smith","Morgan","King","Cole"],
                    "job": ["Engineer","Dentist","Coach","Teacher"],"Age":[25,20,25,30],
                    "Id": [1,2,3,4]})

df.add_suffix("_x")
```

And this is the result:

```
    name_x    surname_x   job_x      Age_x   Id_x
0   John      Smith       Engineer   25      1
1   Alex      Morgan      Dentist    20      2
2   Kate      King        Coach      25      3
3   Martin    Cole        Teacher    30      4
```

But I want to add the first N columns so let's say the first 3. Desired output is:

```
    name_x    surname_x   job_x      Age     Id
0   John      Smith       Engineer   25      1
1   Alex      Morgan      Dentist    20      2
2   Kate      King        Coach      25      3
3   Martin    Cole        Teacher    30      4
```

Answer (score 4):

Work with the indices and take slices to modify a subset of them:

```
df.columns = (df.columns[:3]+'_x').union(df.columns[3:], sort=False)

print(df)
   name_x surname_x     job_x  Age  Id
0    John     Smith  Engineer   25   1
1    Alex    Morgan   Dentist   20   2
2    Kate      King     Coach   25   3
3  Martin      Cole   Teacher   30   4
```

Answer (score 1):

set the column labels using a list comprehension:

```
n = 3
df.columns = [f'{c}_x' if i < n else c for i, c in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

results in

```
   name_x surname_x     job_x  Age  Id
0    John     Smith  Engineer   25   1
1    Alex    Morgan   Dentist   20   2
2    Kate      King     Coach   25   3
3  Martin      Cole   Teacher   30   4
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
N=3
cols=[i for i in df.columns[:N]]
new_cols=[i+'_x' for i in df.columns[:N]]
dict_cols=dict(zip(cols,new_cols))
df.rename(dict_cols,axis=1)
```

Comment: Some of my column names are integers. So this is the answer if you are looking for add a suffix to an integer named columns.